# When would you use без боли vs. безболезненно?

Tags: выбор-слова, словоупотребление, узус

When is it most appropriate to use `без боли` vs. `безболезненно`, and why?

Comment: The difference is roughly the same as in "without pain" vs. "painlessly".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*безболезненно* and *без боли* have a similar meaning "painless". *без боли* is rarely used, usually with an infinitive or a noun in a header or a slogan:

- Стоматология без боли
- Как жить без боли
- Любовь без боли

In these cases *безболезненно* can't be used. It requires a verb that means a short-term action. For example, you can't live *безболезненно*, but you can die.

*безболезненно* is common to describe a short-term painless action:

- безболезненно удалить зуб
- безболезненно умереть

*без боли* can be used in this case, but it will sound strange.

*безболезненно* has another meaning "smooth, trouble-free":

- бесболезненно развестись
- реформа прошла безболезненно

*без боли* can't be used in this case (but you can use *без головной боли* in a figurative meaning).

*без боли* also can be used as a form of *боль*:

- расстаться без боли и сожаления

In this case *безболезненно* can't be used.

Comment: I think the last case can be used with "безболезненно" - for example, "расстаться безболезненно и без сожаления".

Comment: another meaning would be "without consequences", for example "какой из пунктов сметы мы могли бы безболезненно вычеркнуть?" ("what position in the cost estimate could we strike out without consequences?").